# OpenAM exportmetadata giving ERROR: No matching entity metadata found

Tags: metadata, saml-2.0, openam, spring-saml

I had Deployed OpenAM before in my machine and was able to work on it, For Saml Implementation

I was using the link : http://localhost:8080/OpenAM-13.0.0/saml2/jsp/exportmetadata.jsp to export the metadata. It was working fine in my machine.

But now after deploying the same war in someone's else machine when i go to the same link i get ERROR: No matching entity metadata found.

Please help, not able to get any idea what is wrong

-regards Joydeep

Comment: by default the link tries to export the primary hosted IdP Meta data of the default realm. Does it work when you specify request parameter 'entityid' (https://backstage.forgerock.com/#!/docs/openam/13/admin-guide#saml2-create-hosted-idp)

Comment: yes i have tried but its not working, actually the entityID is not set at all, as it is finding NULL i am getting the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a Hosted IDP into OpenAM giving the link http://localhost:8080/OpenAM-13.0.0/ Now its working. Thanks @Bernhard